# Count number of values less than an increasing value

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I want to count the number of values less or equal to 30, then count the number of values less than or equal to 60, less than or equal to 90...etc. I can do this iteratively using the `sum(dat$values <= 30)` but I would like to automate this somehow.

Example

```
set.seed(917)
dat <- as.data.frame(sample(0:2100,100,replace = F))
colnames(dat)[1] <- "values"

sum(dat$values <= 30)
sum(dat$values <= 60)
sum(dat$values <= 90)
sum(dat$values <= 120)
sum(dat$values <= 150)
```

Output should look like

```
  BinWidth TotalValuesLessThan
1       30                   1
2       60                   1
3       90                   2
4      120                   3
5      150                   4
```

I would like to have the output iteratively go out to `BinWidth = 2100` without needing to use `sum(dat$values <= X)` 70 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your bins and apply along them.

```r
BinWidth <- seq(30, 2100, by = 30)
TotalValueLessThan <- sapply(BinWidth, \(x) sum(dat$values <= x))

head(data.frame(BinWidth, TotalValueLessThan))
#>   BinWidth TotalValueLessThan
#> 1       30                  0
#> 2       60                  1
#> 3       90                  3
#> 4      120                  6
#> 5      150                  6
#> 6      180                 10
```

<sup>Change `\(x)` to `function(x)` if you are using R < 4.1.</sup>

Comment: I get the following error with the second line of code: `Error: unexpected input in "TotalValueLessThan <- sapply(BinWidth, \"`

Comment: Change `\(x)` to `function(x)`. It's new lambda shorthand in R >= 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

We can use findInterval:

```
BinWidth <- seq(30, 150, 30)
data.frame(BinWidth, TotalLessThan = findInterval(BinWidth, sort(dat$values)))
##   BinWidth TotalLessThan
## 1       30             0
## 2       60             1
## 3       90             3
## 4      120             6
## 5      150             6
```